# Server lagging - Django + mongodb + cronjob

Tags: django, apache, mongodb, cron, wsgi

I'm deploying a Django application, I'm using apache for the deployement with the module WGSI and mongodb as database.

I got multiple cronjob called every 10min which collect data for many API (using [django-kronos](https://github.com/jgorset/django-kronos)).

When the server was launch every thing was great but after few hours the server start lagging and now he is down. 100% of the cpu is used.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oOvK.png):
[image]

This is one of my crontask:

```
@kronos.register('*/10+2 * * * *')
def update_mongo():
  # init the instagram api
  api = InstagramAPI(client_id = 'SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_KEY',
    client_secret = 'SOCIAL_AUTH_INSTAGRAM_SECRET')

  # Get Last post added in database
  try:
    last_id = Post.objects(keywords = 'news').order_by('-created_at').limit(1)[0].insta_id
  except:
    last_id = 0

  # Get the last Media tagged news
  if last_id != 0:
    results = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name = 'news', min_tag_id = last_id)
  else:
    results = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name = 'news')

  for result in results:
    # if post doesn't exist, we create a new one
    try:
      post = Post.objects.get(insta_id = result.id)
    except:
      post = InstaPost()

    # Init the post and save it in database
    post.save(result)
```

The problem now if that I don't know where is exactly the problem, is it apache + django ? Or this line `post = Post.objects.get(insta_id = result.id)` ?

*EDIT*

I removed the cronjob and get the same problem, after a while Physical Memory and CPU just explosed and server start lagging very hard.

The server is a staging one so very bad one : 1 core, 992 MB RAM

Comment: I see that you use newrelic. You can know which part of the code that use most of the CPU by using new relic.

Comment: @EdwinLunando I installed it only on the server, I m registering my application right now

Comment: You need to find out what happened between 10 and 11. Mongo and Apache are stable code, so unless you configured it strange, those are not the problem. Also, why not just make management commands and call those from *actual* cron?

Comment: @timkofu : I checked the logs, nothing special happen before 10, i rebooted the server around 10:45. About Mongo and Apache I installed them through apt-get and i configure apache to make it work with wsgi. What's the difference between making management commands and use django-kronos ?

Comment: @LolWalid management commands + cron means there is no code in between that may or may not interact badly with your app in general. It's good practice to use as few 3rd party apps as possible.

Comment: @timkofu ok i will change it as soon as i can but i think it's not the problem (see EDIT).

Answer (score 0):

Your charts show memory, disk and cpu activity around the time that the application slows down. This could be because of a memory consumption inside your application. When the application hits its memory limit it will start swapping to disk. Could you also post the chart of swapfile usage?

Comment: There is no swap in the server, it's an amazon test server very little and cheap.

Comment: If not swap memory, then perhaps virtual memory usage? Is there anyway for you to profile your application for memory consumption? Since you're using WSGI, you may find [the Dozer package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Dozer) useful.